# Eclipse lag when calling functions from classes (after typing class.function)

Tags: java, eclipse, lag

### EDIT

I decided to turn of code completion, and whenever I need it, I can just press `CTRL` + `SPACE` and it opens the list of options.

### ORIGINAL

I have been experiencing this for a while now. Even on a fresh start of the IDE the program lags after doing what is listed in the title of the question. I can't seem to find a solution for it.

Here is some relevant information.

-It mostly happens when working with `GUI` (`Swing`) and `Files`, but also sometimes when working with non-`OOP` programming.

-I have the `DevStyle` plugin installed.

-The problem is most likely not related with memory, because I have increased the allocated capacity in the `Eclipse.ini` file to `1024m`,`1536m`to the `Xms`,`Xmx` entries respectively. I've been monitoring the heap space usage in Eclipse and it seems to be fine.

-I usually run Chrome with a few tabs open (music, `this.com`:), etc.). However it lags with nothing but Eclipse open as well.

-The lag persists on all 3 power settings on my laptop (Best battery life, better performance, best performance).

Eclipse Version: Eclipse Java Oxygen (January).

-JDK 8

### -My laptop specs are:

CPU: Intel i3 6100-u @ 2.3 Ghz

RAM: 12 GB

HD: 5400 RPM, 1TB ~ (70% free space)

OS: Windows 10 PRO

I have been monitoring the hardware usage though and this seems not to be the problem. The disk usage stays relatively low at around 0-1%. The CPU never reaches 100%. And The Eclipse IDE uses up to 1,2 GB ram at times.

How do i fix the problem? 
I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let it lag for a while. Eclipse does that because you have code completion turned on. If you really want it to stop and don't need code completion, go to preferences and search for content assist, then turn it off.

Comment: I've thought about this. However, i would like to avoid doing it (even if i know most of what I need, it's good to see the options sometimes. Especially when dealing with GUI). Therefore, I would like to find a different solution. Perhaps it is unsolvable. Maybe the Eclipse code completion algorithms aren't well optimized (the irony).

Comment: This isn't really a solution. I have the same problem. Sometimes I need code hinting and sometimes I don't. Turning it off renders it completely useless.